# How to compile and install kernel modules with dependencies and device tree?

Tags: linux, module, embedded, kernel

**My problem**:

When I tried to compile my `.c` file into a `.ko` file and install it. I get issues with the device tree. So If I run

```bash
sudo insmod my_ov5647.ko
```

I get problems with missing device tree. Also, if I try to `rmmod` the installed modules. It shows a whole list of dependencies and if it removes the dependent modules as well. I get a tainted kernel and the whole system reboots.

**Background**

I am working on a driver (linux module) for the camera sensor that already has a driver in the Raspbian release of the [raspberrypi/linux](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux) repo. It's an I2C-based driver. So, I am trying to develop my own and trying to build and install it on my Pi.

**What I tried**

So I decided to clone the whole kernel and replace the release `.c` file with mine and rebuild the kernel. This is mainly because I am trying to use the `.dtbs` device tree file of this driver.

This is the driver I was trying to replace with mine
[ov5647.c](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-6.6.y/drivers/media/i2c/ov5647.c)
and its device tree file can be found here
[ov5647-overlay.dts](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-6.6.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/ov5647-overlay.dts)

Ideally, when you are using the original release driver. You can overlay it with

```
dtoverlay ov5647
```

That was my solution. It was to build the whole kernel as such and use the `dtoverlay` command to install it. This is the commands I used to compile the kernel.

```bash
echo "Set the KERNEL variable"
export KERNEL=kernel8

echo "Build the media drivers"
sudo make modules_install

echo "Copy the necessary device tree blobs to /boot directory"
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/broadcom/*.dtb /boot/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* /boot/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/dts/overlays/README /boot/overlays/

echo "Copy the kernel image to /boot directory"
sudo cp arch/arm64/boot/Image.gz /boot/$KERNEL.img
```

Also, due to the module dependencies issue. I have to reboot and dtoverlay everytime.

**Conclusion**

How to compile and install modules that have dependencies and come with a specific device tree?

Comment: Have you tried asking here? >> https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @nostromo Yes, small SE sites are more friendly but I believe, this level of high level question from a rep1 user should be welcomed also here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @nostromo. I will post there too. but i will appreciate suggestions here too.